# QNX C/C++ software

Tags: c++, qnx

How can I get QNX C/C++ sample code?

Answer (score 4):

Since QNX is proprietary, it can be hard to get a "jump start".

But as Research In Motion (the makers of BlackBerry) acquired it and are heavily investing on it - in the hopes to get as many developers as possible to jump on the new BBX platform, you may benefit from learning QNX via RIM - and maybe even winning a free Playbook tablet.

You can download the Native Development Kit (NDK) from this website: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/

It is a slightly modified version of Eclipse called Momentics. Using the Playbook simulator (which runs under a - hopefully - free version of VMWare) you can write, compile and run your QNX softwares.

I suggest you taking a close look at PPS objects. They are the most outstanding "idiosyncrasy" of QNX and mastering it will pretty much enable you as a QNX developer. Also, try to register for Foundry27 on QNX website and there you will find handful of (unfortunately almost hidden from Google) resources on QNX.

I hope that helps!

EDIT: and with the NDK it comes with a handful of examples. You will find them pretty much similar to POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

[QNX Community Resources](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs) is always a good source of help and sample code for QNX.

Usually, library reference entries have a small sample code, e.g. [MsgDeliverEvent](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/m/msgdeliverevent.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you go to [QNX.com](http://QNX.com), download the QDE/Momentics trial, you'll get an Eclipse-CDT which will have examples available from the start page.

Answer (score 1):

QNX Neutrino is also similar enough to Linux/Unix systems that most software examples (for example socket and terminal io code) will be equally applicable to QNX as they are for their Unix system.

Comment: QNX implements most, if not all, POSIX interfaces.